# QGIS Label Buffer/Mask Issue

Tags: qgis, labeling, buffer, masking

I have tried this with different QGIS versions (3.14 & 3.16) on both Mac and PC, but am not able to resolve the following problem.

I derived vector contours from a DEM and made labels every 250 m using a Mask in Layer Styling.
I also added a point vector layer with places and made labels using a Buffer, not a Mask.
The issue now is that when I show both layers together the Buffer effect of places does not work. The following image shows an example called Place with the Buffer effect, **without the contour layer activated**. The buffer around Place is actually a 1 mm sized white colour, but using Blend mode "Soft light" in Layer Styling it blends into the background:
[image]

This is the image of **both layers together**:
[image]

The Mask of the contours layer works fine, but the buffer around Place now does not blend into the background, remaining white. No matter what Blend mode I used in Layer Styling, it remains white.

Does anyone have any idea if there could be a problem using Buffer and Mask for different layers together in the same project?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but, on 3.18, I see much the same thing. With some labels, I can just see the underlying map through the buffer when multiplying. On others, I can see them on one side of the label buffer, but not the other. But the Blend Mode seems to be *almost* ignored.

[image]

Turning off the mask gives results like yours (with a big buffer and soft light).

[image]

So, no answer, but confirmation for 3.18.

Comment: Yes not an answer but it does point out a potential issue, regardless the QGIS version. I will now report it on: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues